# Auto-populating user manytomanyfield with Django admin site

Tags: django

I have a class Business, example:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

So the variable `users` in connected with the `Use`r. And let's assume that in the `User`, there are 5 users were created: `Admin`, `Test`, `Test1`, `Test2` and `Test3`. So only `Admin` is the superuser of all the users and let's say that I am logged in using `Test2`. So when I clicked save, the manytomanyfield will be automatically saved with `Test2`, so it is like automatically saved on whoever the `request.user` is.

And also, is there a way to automatically save all the users in the manytomanyfield? thanks.

Comment: Look at this [app](https://github.com/Zapix/whovedonethis). It provides [mixins](https://github.com/Zapix/whovedonethis/blob/master/whovedonethis/models.py) for this functionality.

Comment: this is just a foreignkey @DrTyrsa. I already test with a foreign key code but it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use JavaScript for this, neither do you need to show a form field for `users` if it's meant to be automatically updated. You can instead create a `ModelAdmin` subclass and override the [`save_model` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model). For example:

**In the `admin.py` of your app**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Business

class BusinessAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ["users"]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.id: obj.save()
        obj.users.add(request.user)
        obj.save()
admin.site.register(Business, BusinessAdmin)
```

Comment: Simon Kagwi, is there also a way to save automatically all the users? Thanks for helping me. :D

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "save automatically all the users". If you are talking about associating each `Business` instance with all `Users`, then there is no need for a `users` field in the first place.

Comment: Uhmmmmmm. Like for example, if the superuser creates a business and it should be automatically filtered to all non superuser.

Comment: Create a queryset of all non-superuser users then assign to `obj.users` instead of doing `obj.users.add(request.user)` eg. `obj.users = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=False)`. Obviously you may need to add `if ... else` statements to take care of the different scenarios.